# Why do I get popular question points on questions that have no upvotes?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I often get popular question points/awards for questions that never received any upvotes. What exactly is the rank for popularity; impressions?

Comment: If impressions means the same as page views, then yes. You can see the page view count right under your question where it says "Viewed X times". You get a bronze badge for 1000 views, a silver badge for 2500 views, and a gold badge for 10000 views.

Comment: Samples of such badges are *[Popular Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399)* (1,000 views. Bronze badge), *[Notable Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399)* (2,500 views. Silver  badge), and *[Famous Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399)* (10,000 views. Gold badge).